# How to hide a html overlay label on a sphere object

Tags: three.js

I have a sphere model along with html text labels overlayed onto it at fixed positions. How can I hide them when they are behind the object when i am rotating my sphere using orbit controls?

Anyone knows about any references on stackoverflow or any examples which can solve my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this example how you could do it: http://jsfiddle.net/L0rdzbej/194/

I have put the relevant code in the `updateLabelVisibility()`-function, it looks like this:

```
var meshPosition = mesh.getWorldPosition();
var eye = camera.position.clone().sub( meshPosition );
var dot = eye.clone().normalize().dot( meshPosition.normalize() );

//IS TRUE WHEN THE MESH IS OCCLUDED BY THE SPHERE = dot value below 0.0
var ocluded = dot < -0.2;

if ( ocluded ) {
    // HIDE LABEL IF CAMERA CANT SEE IT (I.E. WHEN IT IS BEHIND THE GLOBE)
  label.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
else { 
  // DISPLAY LABEL IF MESH IS VISIBLE TO THE CAMERA
  label.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Where `mesh` is the marker where your label is attached to. The dot is basically telling you how far around the sphere it is, within a certain distance of 90 degree. Simply said by values below zero the label is longer visible by going further around the back.

To be fair I based this off some code from: https://zeitgeist-globe.appspot.com/